# Analyzing alternating metals in a polymer matrix with 1 micrometer depth and only 10% metal

Tags: spectroscopy, materials, x-ray-diffraction

This is a theoretical question that I am struggling to get started on for a seminar discussion. If you were attempting to design an instrument with all the basic components (source, analyzer, detector, sample holder) what type of each component would you use and why? The sample is alternating layers of heavy metal in a polymer matrix with 1 micrometer depth and 10% metal

My instinct is that if this is a metal we should use the photoelectric effect and potentially look at scattered electrons. If we are looking at electrons some time of photomultipler could amplify the signal but how would the different electrons from different metals be analyzed? What type of source would be most appropriate?

Comment: Could you described the alternating layers in more detail? Thickness? Composition?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question so no, the information on thickness is in the question and it is alternating metal layers

Comment: There have been x-ray diffraction crystals for a wavelength dispersive instrument made by alternating carbon and metal layers which were good for low energy x-rays. But such layering is only useful in a narrow range.

Comment: could you elaborated on what you mean by wavelength dispersive instrument?

Comment: Photoelectrons are pretty low energy so won’t get out from very deep in the sample. Why not RBS?

Comment: My notion is that the layers repeat and are consistent, though the metal layer and the polymer layer might not be the same thickness. Thus you are looking for Bragg diffraction. You have two choices for energy source, x-rays and an electron beam (a moving charge has a wavelength).

Comment: What would be the benefit of x-rays over an electron beam? Presumable the electron beam uses the PE effect but can this penetrate layers? X-rays I assume will diffract differently off of different metals right?